# I can't install published app in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

At the end of April I published my first, small application in the `Play Store`, but there is no Install button. I still see Add to the `WishList`.
In `Play Console` app is marked as a published and there is no any communicate about errors etc. What I did wrong?

Comment: check the app availability for different devices and country too

Comment: Probably you are right! I'll let you know.

Comment: Check your country.

Comment: You are right! Thank you!